# No overseers on thrall world in Stellaris

Tags: stellaris

I've got a bunch of Necroid Thrall Worlds that are just falling into chaos because I can't seem to get the overseer jobs to be filled, even when I have unemployed pops on that planet of the worker stratum.

How can I make these be filled?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that my thrall species actually had residency rights, rather than being slaves.

Only slaves can work as overseers.